# Обстоятельство времени в предложении с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот, обстоятельство

> Назначая встречу, вы часто беспокоитесь о том, чтобы другому человеку было удобно место встречи и назначенное время.

Смысл такой: «в вашей жизни часто происходит так, что, назначая встречу, вы беспокоитесь…"

Если подходить формально, не получается ли, что частое беспокойство происходит не в жизни в целом, а во время назначения встречи, и для синтаксической правильности обязательно нужно поставить «часто» в начало, чтобы отнести его ко всей ситуации?

> Часто, назначая встречу, вы беспокоитесь о том, чтобы другому человеку было удобно место встречи и назначенное время.

Или позиция обстоятельства может быть и такой, как в первоначальном примере, и это не будет ошибкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы патаетесь использовать наречие "часто" как вводное слово со значением "часто бывает", но у него нет таких "полномочий". Во втором варианте разграничение деепричастным оборотом способствует такому восприятию. Это наречие из тех, которые по смыслу примыкают к глаголу, а не определяют смысл всего предложения, в отличие от слова "обычно" (которое на это способно).

Правильно:
*Часто бывает, что, назначая встречу, вы беспокоитесь о том, чтобы другому человеку было удобно место встречи и назначенное время.*
Тут можно сделать логический вывод, что назначение встречи происходит ещё чаще (потому что бывают случаи назначения встречи без беспокойства).

Теперь общий ответ (про все подобные ситуации) на вопрос:

> Или позиция обстоятельства может быть и такой, как в первоначальном примере, и это не будет ошибкой?

Использование позиции, которая даёт значительное преимущество неверному смыслу, является стилистической неточностью (по информации Sharon), не ошибкой, потому что предложение всё равно остаётся корректным. Просто подавляющее число людей поймут неверно.

Answer (score 2):

В первом примере лучше заменить "часто" на "зачастую" ("порой"), иначе возникает побочный смысл "частого беспокойства" после назначения *каждой конкретной* встречи.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен второй раз.

1. ***Назначая встречу**, вы часто беспокоитесь о том, чтобы другому человеку было удобно место встречи и назначенное время.*

В данном случае   деепричастный оборот определяет жизненную ситуацию, которая повторяется неоднократно (часто), что видно по несовершенному виду глагола и деепричастия.  Второе обстоятельство (наречия "обычно, как правило") конкретизирует первое, заданное деепричастным оборотом.  Логика понятная: обозначив ситуацию, мы переходим к деталям.

2. Но логика будет нарушена, если более конкретное и частное поставить впереди общего, поэтому не надо этого делать.

Соответственно, некорректно выглядит второе предложение:  *Обычно, **назначая встречу**, вы беспокоитесь о том, чтобы другому человеку было удобно место встречи и назначенное время.*

3. **Редактирование стиля:** *Назначая кому-либо встречу, вы обычно беспокоитесь о том, чтобы место и время  были для него удобными.*

Comment: Sharon,полностью с вами согласен. Шероховатость стиля сразу бросилась в глаза.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Мне же всегда приятно видеть ваши ответы на вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако в первом пункте вашего ответа все предложенные вами варианты (с придаточным времени и с падежной формой), на мой взгляд, совсем не уточняют смысл. К слову, детерминант относится ко всему составу предложения, поэтому легко можно понять неправильно: «при назначении встречи происходит частое беспокойство».

Comment: Замена «часто» на слово «обычно» действительно решает проблему.

Comment: Мне очень жаль, но вы меня не поняли. 1) Я предлагаю вам только единственный вариант (п.3), который  является  улучшенной редакцией вашего исходного предложения.  2) Также я говорю о том, что ваш второй вариант не подходит вовсе. Там нет и не может быть значения уточнения, но ЛЮБОЙ обособленный оборот в такой позиции приобретает характер ВСТАВКИ.  Если его убрать  из  предложения, то  оно вообще потеряет смысл, а при такой структуре всё выглядит именно так и читается именно так (как будто его убрали).

Comment: Все остальные объяснения, возможно, лишние, но это совсем не варианты предложения, а всего лишь не очень удачные попытки объяснить семантику  деепричастного оборота. Извините, что не получилось этого сделать.  С вашего разрешения я уберу лишний материал.

Comment: Теперь понял. И всё‑таки, вариант в вашем пункте 1 верно передаёт нужный смысл или неверно? Просто непонятно, к чему вы рассказываете о том, что деепричастный оборот — детерминант, а слово «часто» присловный распространитель. Какой вывод следует из того? Вы будто подразумеваете из этого какой‑то вывод, но, к сожалению, я пока не научился считывать ваши мысли на расстоянии :-)

Comment: Убираю детерминант,  пишу третью редакцию, но уж точно последнюю. Наречие "часто" заменяю наречием "обычно".